# Changing decimal field scale and precision using database

Tags: 7, entities, database

I'm using a custom decimal field in a custom product type in Drupal commerce. It has a precision of 10 and a scale of 2 (2 digits to the right of the decimal place).

I have a client with a large number of products that use this field, but their specification has now changed to require a decimal to 3dp.

By default Drupal "locks" the field to avoid data loss:

> Because the field already has data, some settings can no longer be
>   changed.

I took to editing the database, and it seems to have worked fine. I did three things:

1. Changed the structure type of `field_THIS_FIELD_value` field in the `drupal_field_data_THIS_FIELD` table from `decimal(10,2)` to `decimal(11,3)`
2. Repeated the same for the field revision table
3. I downloaded the BLOB from table 'drupal_field_config' for `field_THIS_FIELD` and altered `{s:9:"precision";s:2:"10";s:5:"scale";s:1:"2"` to `{s:9:"precision";s:2:"11";s:5:"scale";s:1:"3"`

I cleared cache and existing data now has an extra 0 after the decimal place, and when I alter the data it stores it to 3 decimal places.

So it seems to work fine. But am I missing anything? Is there anywhere else where field data is changed that I might need to change?

Does the system integrity remain intact? I think I've done what's necessary but don't want to inadvertently break something else or cause any weakness in the system.

Comment: OK I created a new instance to check the BLOB in `drupal_field_config_instance` matched the existing one. Anything else?

Comment: FYI my action plan worked fine.

Comment: Hi, this could be related to my need : http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/231596/change-text-field-editor-in-database-after-upgrade

Could you explain how to replace the updated blob file ( editor, transfer..) ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

you could create a new field with the settings you need and import the data from the old field. 
see: https://www.drupal.org/node/1491590#comment-9682599

Comment: Hey Ahmed, don't want to do that as there is a lot of data and field is linked with modules. My solution seems to work, so question really is whether it's adequate and if I have overlooked anything.

Comment: Ok, I think the doc is missing in drupal, "what changes have to be made" if you want to change field settings after data has been filled in